# "ImportError: No module named requests_html" after installing requests-html to pip and pip3

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, python-requests-html

Tried installing requests-html through pip and pip3 in many different ways (recommendations from other StackOverflow threads) and I keep on getting the same error ImportError: No module named requests_html.

Checked pip and pip3 list, both of them have requests and requests-html. Also my python is updated, its 3.7.6.

Also weirdly I started writing the code on jupyter notebook, and everything worked, however when I switched to sublime text that's where the problem occurred.

Please help.

P.s. I am on a mac, and I am a beginer.

Comment: @Gnudiff With a hyphen, there is a syntax error SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Plus looked at some tutorials they had an underscore when importing.

Comment: Have you installed multiple versions of python in your machine? Maybe you are calling a different Python interpreter than you expect. Try to run these two commands: `which pip3` and `which python3` and post the results (censure sensitive folder names if needed)

Comment: @lax48 Yes, i think so. which pip3 gives me /opt/anaconda3/bin/pip3 and which python3 gives me /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3

Comment: Could you try to install another package in order to undestand if the issue is related to `requests_html` or  pip/python?

Comment: @lax48 installed botocore (pip install botocore), and the same issue occurs. Probably the issue here is with pip/python

Comment: Ok, how have you installed python? From the official website as a zip, from the command line (and if so, please could you post it) or from a third party? Also try to `cd` the directory where python and pip is installed and call them using `./pip` and `./python`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222789/discussion-between-lax48-and-markas-povilaika).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue where Sublime was using the wrong Python Environment.

You need to add a new build configuration:

1. Check where is your Python3 path (using which or where commands, depending on your os)
2. Add and configure the build system (look at the link below or google how to do it)
3. Select the newly created build system

Source: https://medium.com/@hariyanto.tan95/set-up-sublime-text-3-to-use-python-3-c845b742c720

Answer (score 0):

I am no Mac expert but.. I know Mac has its own python2 and 3 inner versions which is critical for the OS to operate, so you maybe installed pip into those ones instead of the ones you are operating via PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying everything in command line.

MacOS is based on Unix and it is very command line friendly.

I also recommend working with Python virtual envs, so create a virtual env and then install what you need there.

Go to a folder where you want to create the Python virtualenvs, and create a virtualenv called learn for example, then install requests_html in there:

```
mkdir ~/venvs
cd ~/venvs
python3 -m venv learn

source learn/bin/activate
learn/bin/pip install requests-html
```

Then when running your project, make sure you have that virtual env activated

```
source learn/bin/activate
```

It is useful at this stage to confirm if the python program used is the one from your virtual env so try

```
which python
which python3
```

And let us know the answer. Ideally either python or python3 is the one from within the virtualenv. Then, with the good one, try:

```
python myproject.py
```

You got the import correctly, it should be in your file, myproject.py

```
import requests_html
```

Comment: Thanks, however after creating the virtual env and writing source learn/bin/activate, then python myproject.py (my own file name) I get an error. python3: can't open file 'web.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Hi @MarkasPovilaika you need to be in the terminal in the same folder where web.py is located. Also see my answer as I edited it to show more details about how to verify if the python used is the one within the virtualenv